# Setting up / Troubleshooting Continuity-Camera

Tags: iphone, wifi, bluetooth, continuity

Symptom: Greyed-out 'continuity-camera' options:

- Take Photo
- Scan Documents

[image]

Context:

- Catalina 10.15.7: Wired (ethernet) into network
- iPhone IOS 14.1: Bluetooth indicates connected to Catalina, wifi connected to same LAN

The Mac's wifi is kaput.  **Is the LAN ethernet connection a viable substitute for wifi from a camera continuity context?**

If your setup has a wired ethernet connection and continuity-camera is functional, please post and indicate as such.  Thank you

Asus USB-BT400 installed on Catalina:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, you want bluetooth and WiFi for best discovery and cross device functionality and response from continuity and handoff features. Ideally there is no interference as well once your radios are working again. External Bluetooth works great for continuity when I have a machine that’s difficult or costly to repair.

Just be sure you buy a device that you can get good support if they don’t use Apple drivers effectively or return the product if it fails to work.

- [Continuity and Handoff Bluetooth Setup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405699/continuity-and-handoff-bluetooth-setup)

Comment: Thank you for responding with insight: based on the last screenshot uploaded, are you suggesting that I return the external Asus USB-BT400 installed on Catalina?